# Cython - how to properly call operator with references

Tags: python, c++, cython

I have the following code in my Cython wrapper to a C++ code:

```
# distutils: language = c++
# distutils: sources = symbolic.cpp
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
from libcpp.pair cimport pair
from libcpp.string cimport string
from libcpp cimport bool

cdef extern from "symbolic.h" namespace "metadiff::symbolic":
    cdef cppclass SymbolicMonomial:
        vector[pair[int, int]] powers
        long long coefficient;
        SymbolicMonomial()
        SymbolicMonomial(long)
        SymbolicMonomial(const SymbolicMonomial&)
        bool is_constant()
        long long int eval(vector[int]&)
        long long int eval()
        string to_string()
        string to_string_with_star() const

    cdef SymbolicMonomial mul_mm"operator*"(const SymbolicMonomial&, const SymbolicMonomial&)
    # SymbolicMonomial operator*(long long, const SymbolicMonomial&)
    # SymbolicMonomial operator*(const SymbolicMonomial&, long long)


cdef class SymMonomial:
    cdef SymbolicMonomial* thisptr      # hold a C++ instance which we're wrapping
    def __cinit__(self):
        self.thisptr = new SymbolicMonomial()
    def __cinit__(self, int value):
        self.thisptr = new SymbolicMonomial(value)
    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.thisptr
    def is_constant(self):
        return self.thisptr.is_constant()
    def eval(self):
        return self.thisptr.eval()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.to_string_with_star()
    def to_string(self):
        return self.thisptr.to_string().decode('UTF-8')
    def to_string_with_star(self):
        return self.thisptr.to_string_with_star().decode('UTF-8')
    def __mul__(self, other):
        return mul_mm(self.thisptr, other)
def variable(variable_id):
    monomial = SymMonomial()
    monomial.thisptr.powers.push_back((variable_id, 1))
    return monomial
```

However, I never figured it out how to call the `mul_mm` method correctly. It keeps saying `Cannot convert 'SymbolicMonomial' to Python object` or vice versa. The thing is I need to be able to multiply two SymMonomials in this way. However for some reason I can not get the hang of it of how to do it properly. Any advices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of issues:

1. You can't return C++ objects directly to Python - you need to return your wrapper type (assign to `thisptr` of the wrapper)
2. You can't guarantee either `self` or `other` is of the correct type at the point the function is called (see the note in http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/special_methods.html#arithmetic-methods about how the methods can be called with the operands in either order). To use the C/C++ members of a Cython class you need to ensure Cython knows that object is indeed of that class. I recommend using the `<Classname?>` style cast (note the question mark) which throws an exception if it doesn't match.
3. You need to get `thisptr` from `other` too, rather than just passing the Python wrapper class to your C++ function.

The following should work.

```
def __mul__(self,other):
    cdef SymMonomial tmp = SymMonomial()
    cdef SymMonomial self2, other2
    try:
        self2 = <SymMonomial?>self
        other2 = <SymMonomial?>other
    except TypeError:
        return NotImplemented # this is what Python expects for operators
                      # that don't know what to do
    tmp.thisptr[0] = mul_mm(self2.thisptr[0],other2.thisptr[0])
    return tmp
```

Comment: Hey, I think your suggestion solved some of the problem. However, I'm still getting this:```/home/alex/work/c/swig_test/symbolic.h:298: multiple definition of `metadiff::symbolic::operator*(metadiff::symbolic::SymbolicMonomial const&, metadiff::symbolic::SymbolicMonomial const&)'
```, because of the mul_mm renaming. Do you have any idea why that happens? I have guard in my header file, but for some reason it seems to be including it twice?

Comment: Actually I found the problem.